Can a wizard learn a spell from a cleric or druid?
In Pathfinder 2e one can learn a spell assuming one has an instructor who can teach the spell. I'm interested in expanding my spell library, and I'm traveling with a druid and a cleric. I've noticed at least a few of the spells are in common, such as Detect Magic. Can I learn spells from them?

Yes
The Learn a Spell activity has a few different criteria, but there does not appear to be a requirement that the source that you're learning from match your magical tradition, instead it says:

...and the spell you want to learn is on your magical tradition's spell list.

and

You can gain access to a new spell of your tradition from someone who knows that spell...

It notably does not indicate that the other person must know the spell in the same magical tradition.
Furthermore, it appears that if you are strictly a wizard, you must use Arcana to add to your spell. This is indicated by the example provided:

If you can cast spells of multiple traditions, you can Learn a Spell of any of those traditions, but you must use the corresponding skill to do so. For example, if you were a cleric with the bard multiclass archetype, you couldn't use Religion to add an occult spell to your bardic spell repertoire.

Thus, when you are learning a spell for a tradition, you must use the tradition's corresponding skill to do so.

It is not explicitly required that attempting to learn Detect Magic as a Wizard from a Druid will have a higher DC, however, it's possible the GM may still apply an increased DC:

Attempt a skill check for the skill corresponding to your tradition (DC determined by the GM, often close to the DC on the Learning a Spell Table)


That makes perfect sense, allow it to happen but with a higher DC than normal. Thanks!
